# How to implement multiple conditions in if and elif statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue with a condition I'm trying to implement. Fist of all it is not recognising `Select(pax_one_ob_meal)` which makes me think that maybe I'm trying to call on the `<select`> tag incorrectly in this instance but virtually I'm trying to write a condition that does the following:

1. Check to see if the `no_thanks` button is displayed or visible, if so then perform all the actions in the meal drop own meals and then move onto check if `yes_insurance` is displayed or visible, if so then perform the insurance actions, then after that click on the 'Continue' button `driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$forwardButton')`.
2. If there is no `no_thanks` button, then check to see if there is `yes_insurance`, if so then perform the insurance actions and then click on 'Continue' button.
3. If there is no `no thanks` button nor is there `yes_insurance` displayed, then simply click on the continue button.

Do I need to implement multiple conditions in the if and else if statement for these? Can somebody give me an example on how to implement this in python?

Below is what I've tried at the moment:

```
#meals dropdowns
pax_one_ob_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown")
pax_one_ib_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn")
pax_two_ob_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown")
pax_two_ib_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn")
pax_three_ob_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDown")
pax_three_ib_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn")
pax_four_ob_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown")
pax_four_ib_meal = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn")
no_thanks = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_removeMealButton")

#insurance

yes_insurance = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_TravelInsuranceView_insuranceRequiredYes')
single_trip = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="ctl00_MainContent_TravelInsuranceView_insuranceProduct1" and not(@disabled)]')


if no_thanks.is_displayed():
    Select(pax_one_ob_meal)
    pax_one_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDown")))
    Select(pax_one_ib_meal)
    pax_one_ib_meal.select_by_index(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl02_mealsDropDownIn")))

    Select(pax_two_ob_meal)
    pax_two_ob_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown")))
    Select(pax_two_ib_meal)
    pax_two_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDownIn")))

    Select(pax_three_ob_meal)
    pax_three_ob_meal.select_by_index(2)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDown")))
    Select(pax_three_ib_meal)
    pax_three_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl04_mealsDropDownIn")))

    Select(pax_four_ob_meal)
    pax_four_ob_meal.select_by_index(0)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDown")))
    Select(pax_four_ib_meal)
    pax_four_ib_meal.select_by_index(1)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl05_mealsDropDownIn")))

elif yes_insurance.is_displayed():
    yes_insurance.click()
    single_trip.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="insurance-button-submit" and (@disabled="false")]')
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_TravelInsuranceView_InsuranceSubmitButton').click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ct100_MainContent_PageTransitionDialog_messageWrapper")))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_forwardButton"))).click()

else:    
    driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$MainContent$forwardButton')
```

Below are the HTML tags for `no_thanks`, `yes_insurance` and the continue button:

No Thanks

```
<input type="submit" class="buttonnomeals" title="No thanks!" id="ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_removeMealButton" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$InFlightMeal$removeMealButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" value="No thanks!" name="ctl00$MainContent$InFlightMeal$removeMealButton">
```

Insurance

`<input type="radio" value="insuranceRequiredYes" name="ctl00$MainContent$TravelInsuranceView$insuranceRequired" id="ctl00_MainContent_TravelInsuranceView_insuranceRequiredYes">`

Continue

```
<input type="submit" class="buttonforward" title="Checkout" id="ctl00_MainContent_forwardButton" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$forwardButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" value="Checkout" name="ctl00$MainContent$forwardButton">
```

Comment: the logic should be like this: `if no_thanks and yes_insurance:...elif yes_insurance and no no_thanks:... else:...`